# How to retrieve DEX from dex wireless adaptor with iOS CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, gatt

I currently have a DEX BLE-1 adaptor from Honeywell used to retrieve dex data from vending machines. I have a swift 3 iOS app that uses CoreBluetooth to make scans and pair to the peripheral. The adaptor has has three services: serial port, battery, and dex service. The dex service has three characteristics: firmware version, session, and settings. I suppose the session characteristic is used to retrieve the dex; however, I am not sure how to do so.

I use the didUpdateValueFor peripheral method to get the value relating to the uuid of the characteristic of session but the value is nil.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        if characterstic.uuid.uuidString == uuidSession {
            if(characteristic.value != nil) {
                print(characterstic.value)
            }
        }
}
```

Is the DEX supposed to be retrieved from the session characteristic value? It seems to be a few bytes, maybe I have to concatenate the bytes? But the value is nil anyways. I am new at this but should this be done through the serial port? I read somewhere you could establish a connection through it, or is this totally off?

Comment: Did you answer for above? Do we need to use any SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The DEX communication with a vending machine is a serial port connection.

The new Blu-DEX is BLE 4.0 and works with both Android and Apple.

Comment: So, the DEX BLE-1 adaptor does not support serial port connection? I do see the service and characteristics data and status. I would have to get the other one?

Comment: The problem is I get the serial port service in my iOS app using core bluetooth. I get the "data" characteristic of the service and it's null. How do you retrieve the dex through this service tho? Can the DEX be stored in the characteristic?

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking for characterstic  or for the value ?

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    let readValue = characteristic.value
    if let str = String(data: readValue!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print("Line \(index): \(str)")
        index += 1
    } else {
        print("Received an invalid string!")
    }

}
```